# Why is nothing displaying in my listbox? C#

Tags: c#, listbox

My program is supposed to take team names from an XML file and display them in the listbox, and when a team is selected from the listbox, players with a higher batting average on the team are displayed in a datagridview. For some reason nothing is showing up in my listbox, and therefore I cannot select anything and test if my program works.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataSet resultset = new DataSet();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultset.ReadXml("Baseball.xml");

        var myQuery = resultset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new
        {
            teamname = row.Field<string>("Team")
        })
        .Distinct();

        foreach (var rowname in myQuery)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(rowname.teamname.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double TotalhitsAverage, TotalatBatAverage, TeamAverage;
        DataTable playerInformation = new DataTable();
        DataRow[] tableName = resultset.Tables[0].Select("Team = '" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "'");

        playerInformation = tableName.CopyToDataTable();
        DataTable clonedcolumns = playerInformation.Clone();

        clonedcolumns.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(double);
        clonedcolumns.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(double);

        foreach (DataRow row in playerInformation.Rows)
        {
            clonedcolumns.ImportRow(row);
        }

        TotalhitsAverage = clonedcolumns.AsEnumerable().Average(r => r.Field<double>("hits"));

        TotalatBatAverage = clonedcolumns.AsEnumerable().Average(r => r.Field<double>("atBats"));

        TeamAverage = TotalhitsAverage / TotalatBatAverage;

        DataTable playerAverage = new DataTable();
        DataRow rowPlayer = playerAverage.NewRow();

        playerAverage.Columns.Add("Player", typeof(String));
        playerAverage.Columns.Add("Batting Avg", typeof(double));

        for (int i = 0; i < clonedcolumns.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            double averageplayer = Convert.ToDouble(clonedcolumns.Rows[i][3]) / Convert.ToDouble(clonedcolumns.Rows[i][2]);

            if (TeamAverage <= averageplayer)
            {
                playerAverage.Rows.Add(clonedcolumns.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Math.Round(averageplayer, 4));
            }
        }
        DataView view = playerAverage.DefaultView;
        view.Sort = "Batting Avg DESC";
        DataTable sortedDate = view.ToTable();
        dgvBaseball.DataSource = sortedDate;
        dgvBaseball.AutoSize = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your dataset get populated?

Comment: This is a classic case of writing a bunch of code, pressing the big go button and wondering why it doesn’t work. You **ARE** now a programmer, we **don’t** do this. You **NEED** to debug your code so **YOU** can identify at each point in code what is going on (after all you wrote it), **YOU** need inspect each line while it is running to determine if it has **YOUR** expected values, and if you can’t figure it out then you come to stack overflow with the results of those tests, the line that is not working, the expected results and the reasoning. You have none of this

Comment: This comment isn't sarcastic - it's for real. Click on the margin to the left of the line of code *after* `resultset.ReadXml`. You'll see a dot appear. It's called a breakpoint. Run the program again. When the program gets to that line it will stop. Move your mouse over the word `resultset` and Visual Studio will let you see what's in `resultset`, or more specifically, `resultset.Tables[0]`. My guess is nothing. So this really has nothing to do with a `ListBox`.

Comment: @TheGeneral Okay, I will make sure to gather all this information before asking here. My apologies.

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**